# Resize background video - SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I've created a background video in swift. But by any reason the video is way to small. It's not covering the whole screen like it supposed to.

This is the result at the moment. What I'm trying to do is to cover the whole screen.

[image: result]

```
private func setupView()
{
    let path = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "mydogwalkvideo", ofType: ".mp4")!)

    let player = AVPlayer(url: path)

    let newLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    newLayer.frame = self.videoView.frame
    self.videoView.layer.addSublayer(newLayer)
    newLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill //It's set to resize aspect to fill

    player.play()
    player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayer.ActionAtItemEnd.none


    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.videoDidPlayToEnd(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification"), object: player.currentItem)

}

@objc func videoDidPlayToEnd(notification: Notification)
{
    let player: AVPlayerItem = notification.object as! AVPlayerItem
    player.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
}
```

Additional information:

The video size is normally 1920x1080

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update frame inside the method `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    self.newLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.videoView.frame = self.view.bounds
}
```

Comment: You're a hero, thanks a lot for that input. Saved my day, hehe.